# registerForContextMenu for menuItems

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextmenu

Ok I'm sure this is a dumb question but I couldn't find the answer online. I want to register one of the menu Items for a context Menu, but I don't know how to can't figure out how to access the MenuItem as a view. So when I click one of the buttons on the ActionBar of my application, I want a context menu to pop up. I'm guessing this has to be done in OnCreateOptionsMenu?

Edit: Update... Adding this code works partially but overrides my Drawable.

XML

```
<item android:id="@+id/Favorites" 
      android:title="favorite_label" 
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces" 
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
      android:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

Main Activity

```
        FavoriteButton = (ImageButton) menu.findItem(R.id.Favorites).getActionView();

        FavoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                registerForContextMenu(v);
            }
        });
```

Comment: registerForContextMenu() is usually not for the actionBar buttons. It is used for Views (ListView, GridView, ...). See the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi follow below link [exmple link](http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/)

```
 ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, Countries);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
registerForContextMenu(list);
```

change registerForContextMenu(list); to registerForContextMenu(buttonname);

i hope it useful to you.

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to find where it mentions anything about an item from the ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

In the resource/menu/main.xml add the below code:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >         
                 <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/gray"
                    android:title="@string/gray" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/green"                      
                    android:title="@string/green" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/red"                      
                    android:title="@string/red" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/orange"                       
                    android:title="@string/orange" />           

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/purple"
                    android:title="@string/dark_blue" />
            </menu>

                </item>
        </menu>
```

and in the main activity you can access this by overridding the belo method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {           
        switch (item.getItemId()) {   
                    case R.id.gray:
            color = Color.parseColor("#FF666666");              
            return true;

        case R.id.green:
            color = Color.parseColor("#FF96AA39");              
            return true;

        case R.id.orange:
            color = Color.parseColor("#FFF4842D");              
            return true;

        case R.id.purple:
            color = Color.parseColor("#FF5161BC");              
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Are you answering my Question? I'm confused what your implying?

Comment: yes answering your questn..when I click one of the buttons on the ActionBar of my application, I want a context menu to pop up...In this list of colours will appear as a submenu items.

Comment: I just ran your code and failed to achieve this. All I am noticing is when you click on a specific button on the ActionBar it changes the color and toast the name of the Menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have made:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // "menu_main" is the menubar of my actionbar menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}



public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // "item" is the menu button I have pressed
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // "Settings" button
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    // Difficulty button to change the difficulty of my game
    else if (id == R.id.action_difficulty) {
        View view = findViewById(R.id.action_difficulty);
        registerForContextMenu(view);
        openContextMenu(view);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This works fine for me!

BUT! If your menubar button is behind the "three dots" button, the line

```
registerForContextMenu(view);
```

will crash your application. I'm figuring out why..